# fillna pandas doesn't affect original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'm trying to fill missing values for specific column but the original data frame doesn't change though I'm using `inplace=True`
I tried this:

```
all_data.loc[all_data['GarageType'] == 'Detchd', 'GarageCond'].fillna('TA', 
inplace=True)
```

and this:

```
all_data.fillna({x:'TA' for x in ['GarageCond'] if ['GarageType'] ==  
'Detchd'}, inplace=True)
```

Edite : 
this worked

```
all_data.fillna({x:'TA' for x in ['GarageCond'] if 
(all_data['GarageType']=='Detchd').any()}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your version and environment?

Try this and let me know:

```
all_data = all_data.fillna({x:'TA' for x in ['GarageCond'] if ['GarageType'] ==  
                           'Detchd'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I'm using jupyter, python3 

    all_data.fillna({x:'TA' for x in ['GarageCond'] if (all_data['GarageType'] ==  
    'Detchd').any()}, inplace=True)

this worked , thanks